# Primary Key Column Name with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following setup with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate as the persistence provider. All of my entities inherit from a base class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

  @Id  
  private id;

  @Version
  private String version;

  //more common fields
}
```

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends BaseEntity {

}
```

This leads to a primary key column with name "ID" to be generated on the "FOO" table. I would like to change the naming of the primary key column. It should reflect the name of class or table. So it should be "FOO_ID" instead of just "ID".

I know that I could do this statically by using @Column(name = "FOO_ID"). But that would mean I have to do this for every Entity. Is there a more dynamic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but stumbled across this looking for an answer...  Eventually found this solution elsewhere:

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="FOO_ID"))
public class Foo extends BaseEntity {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your subClasses will have the same ID column name because of the inheritance, you can specify a common id colum name for all subClasses in the Base entity Class

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make the id column name dependent on the class/table name? So that it would be FOO_ID for table FOO and BAR_ID for table BAR.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why use inheritance then? Just do it without inheritance.
2. You could use getters/setters to rename your fields

Ex:

```
class Foo {

  private Long id;

  public Long getFooId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setFooId(Long fooId) {
    this.id = fooId;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought of inheritance because basically all subclassed entities follow the same naming convention. Could you please elaborate a bit more on option 2.?